# How to create a flood fill figure animation using python?

Tags: python, image, recursion, matplotlib, flood-fill

How to create flood fill figure animation using python?

I saw this image online and was wondering how to go about these types of animation. I think this is a very useful technique that can be used in maps, presentations, etc and was curious about it.

The image:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyYms.gif

I Researched these questions:

- [Flood Fill in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839947/flood-fill-in-python)
- [How to flood-fill part of a bitmap enclosed by a black border with my chosen color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026346/python-how-to-flood-fill-part-of-a-bitmap-enclosed-by-a-black-border-with-my-ch)
- [Python: floodfill algorithm for minesweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711011/python-floodfill-algorithm-for-minesweeper)
- [Flood Fill Algorithm Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746766/flood-fill-algorithm-python)

Looked at this resource:

- http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2011/08/11/recursion-explained-with-the-flood-fill-algorithm-and-zombies-and-cats/

Questions:

- Can you point me to working code that does this type of exercise?
- Which libraries are considered standard to use now?
- How does the logic behind the fill exercise work?
- Can you point me to more information/resources (maybe the docs for the libraries)
- How could I integrate this concept with matplotlib? Can you point me to an example?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to answer your question in its current form. Have you tried writing any code? Maybe try to write some, see how far you get on your own, and come back here when you get stuck with a particular problem.

Comment: @damian, will do. Somewhat tricky to ask a good question. I even tried to do so! :) I just wanted a starting point I guess, and to have some general pointers on how to go about it. Thank you though

Comment: I would use an `AxesImage` (via imshow) for the fill pattern with a `LineCollection` laid on top for the maze pattern.  You the use `FuncAnimation` to update date the image to be shown in the `AxesImage` as you fill it in.